# How to fix Uncaught Error in onSnapshot: FirebaseError: The query requires an index. on dynamic sorting?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a query where I am querying in a `desc` order using as follows

```
  const { id } = userDetails;
  const initialQuery = await firestore().collection('class')
    .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
    .where(`access.readAccess.${id}`, '==', true)
    .limit(5);
  initialQuery.onSnapshot((documentSnapshots) => {
    const { docs } = documentSnapshots;
    const lastVisible = docs.length > 0 ? docs[docs.length - 1] : '';
    console.log(docs);
  })
```

```
const getMore = async(store, userDetails) => {
  const { id } = userDetails;
  const { lastVisible } = lastState;
  const initialQuery = await firestore().collection('class')
    .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
    .where(`access.readAccess.${id}`, '==', true).startAfter(lastVisible)
    .limit(5);
  const documentSnapshots = await initialQuery.get();
  const { docs } = documentSnapshots;
}
```

When I do this I get an error of `The query requires an index` which seems fair and also helpful url to create the indexing. As I create the indexing it creates indexing of

```
class
access.readAccess.`1571158795762` Ascending createdAt Descending
Collection
Enabled
```

Now in this `1571158795762` will keep changing based on the user logged in. So, of course, it started complaining about the other user. Also, `onSnapshot` doest get called with `desc` order.
Any suggestion, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Cloud Firestore index needs to know about all of the specific fields participating in the query.  This is how it can optimize the query.  If one of your query fields is dynamically named, such as your `access.readAccess.${id}`, then this sort of query is not well suited for Firestore.

The only way around this is to restructure you data in such a way that's compatible with Firestore's requirements for the index.  Since we're not given a good view into the data you're trying to store, it's not really possible to give a working suggestion.  But I will say that moving the IDs into a list and checking that list for the existence of the ID in the query might be helpful.

Comment: Yup, I released that right after I posted the question. Thanks for confirming. Just in case someone troubling with a similar case, I was trying to see read access for the user, and if he had access then show those data, which was an object with keys of userId and value to true. Which I switched to an array and switched the query to `.where('access.readAccess', 'array-contains', id)`, works so smooth.

Comment: Glad you got it working.  If my answer was helpful, please mark it as correct.